# maven build with jenkins not picking up jar from local .m2 repository

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a jenkins job for building my maven project(say project A) which has a dependency on a jar created by another local project(say project B). The jar is present in my local .m2 repo but Jenkins fails to find it in the local repo and goes to search it in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) which obviously it will not find and hence my job fails. I have performed the below checks before posting this question here :

1. The version of the artifact in the dependent and independent projects match
2. The local .m2 repository of my machine has the required dependency jar version
3. Wrote a separate jenkins job to build project B, it built successfully and the jar is present in the .m2 repository of Jenkins home as well the path to which is /var/lib/jenkins/.m2 (In case jenkins is trying to find the jar in its own .m2 repository)
4. Changed the Jenkins"Global Tools configuration" for Maven installation from Manual (I had manually set up the maven home) to Automatic Installation(Version 3.3.9). NO luck, the issue remained the same.
5. NO change has been made to the maven settings.xml.
6. If I try to build Project A manually without Jenkins by using `mvn clean install`, it builds successfully.

So, Its only with Jenkins that I am not able to build the project.

Here is my POM for Project A

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.akamai</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobra-tracer-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>cobra-tracer</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>cobra-tracer</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        //some dependencies here
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.akamai.aps</groupId>
            <artifactId>logger-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The POM for Project B is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.akamai.aps</groupId>
    <artifactId>logger-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>logger-service</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: please share you poms

Comment: Do you expect Jenkins to use your LOCAL maven repository? I would expect you to deploy (not install) Project B to jenkins' maven repo or jenkins to do the build of Project B himself. That way jenkins should find the dependency.

Comment: does it try to download jar remotely? also point 2. do u have POM too available? can you share console output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have integrated jenkins with maven is not correct. You have to use either [artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) or [nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype), both of them have free versions that are sufficiently good to use. You build your project B and deploy them to above repository manager and your project A downloads it from repository manager.

For your specific problem, check

1. In your project configuration, [private repository option](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17391) is checked. This will create separate repository for each jenkins executor. If your executor in jenkins master are different for A and B, you will not see your jar files.
2. In your setup, you can't add any slaves. All build should run on master. I hope you are not running them in separate slaves.
3. I am assuming that you have run your project 'B' using `mvn install`. In your project 'A' run maven command using -U flag. `mvn -U install`.
4. Look at your jenkins job command line. Ensure that it is not running maven with -s flag. This is a way to pass different setting.xml. Example `mvn -s /home/jenkins/setting.xml install`. There is an option to define a different settings file in jenkins project configuration.
5. Look at your maven installation path. It should be in jenkins-workspace/tools location. Check setting.xml inside /conf. Ensure that local repository is not defined. If jenkins is installing it, then it should not be set.
6. Check if in your .m2 folder there is setting.xml file which has a different repo path.

Let me know how it goes.

---

Since you have added artifactory in your workflow now and facing plugin not found problem, add the following in your settings.xml

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
   <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
   <name>remote-repos</name>
   <url>http://<artifactory-ip>:<artifactory-port>/artifactory/repo</url>
   <id>remote-repos</id>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>

<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <snapshots>
     <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
   <id>central</id>
   <name>plugins-release</name>
   <url>http://<artifactory-id>:<artifactory-port>/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
  </pluginRepository>
 <pluginRepository>
   <snapshots />
     <id>snapshots</id>
    <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
    <url>http://<artifactory-id>:<artifactory-port>/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
 </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I am assuming that you have already added repository tag.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, 

Thanks for you reply.
I had set-up Artifactory on the same machine, but was continously facing connection reset issue, hence tried to first build the Project using local maven repository. I am adding answers to your suggestions point wise :

1.The maven project configuration has 'default ~/.m2 repository' selected, so separate repositories are not being created for the projects A and B
2.I am running everything on a single machine, no slaves.

Comment: 3. Yes I run Project B with mvn install.Project A I tried running with 'mvn -U install' but no luck, faced the same issue.   4.I am not using -s switch with maven to specify a different setting file.  5.checked the settings file in jenkins-workspace/tools location,local repository is not defined.  6.There is no settings file in either local .m2 or jenkins .m2 folder.

Comment: Hi Riyanka, Could you also check the permission on jar file created by Project B ? I am wondering if this is a permission issue. However, I do feel that if you manage to solve this problem, you would still need to have repository manager. Why don't you solve this problem as it is more long term solution.

Comment: Hi Gaurav,I configured Artifactory with Jenkins using the Artifactory plugin and now Project B's jar is present in Artifactory in libs-release-local repo. Now in Project A's job,I have added config to resolve artifacts from libs-release-local. I am getting the below error :  [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 in artifactory-release (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Hi Gaurav,I tried out the settings.xml that you suggested along with my repository tags.The download of the maven-resources-plugin:jar failed due to authorization error.I tried to provide the same in maven settings.xml server tags,in the below format: <username>admin</username>
<password></password>  This needs to have an encrypted admin password from artifactory which can be fetched as mentioned in the doc https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Centrally+Secure+Passwords .I am using artifactory 5.0.0. and do not see the show icon to get the encrypted password in Security Configuration.

Comment: It is not mandatory to define encrypted password. You can achieve the same later. In your settings.xml, you should also provide the id of your repository along with username and password using <id> tag. Also, in your artifactory, you should allow anonymous access. Admin->security->General

Comment: Hi Guarav, the build is finally Success!! I used mvn -emp to encrypt my artifactory admin password and provided that in the settings.xml.Also, I allowed anonymous access in Admin->security->General and it worked. I then unchecked the allowed anonymous access option,deleted the artifact from artifactory and built again,It was successful.I guess the encrypted password worked.Thanks a lot for your help !!